# NancyFx using embedded views

Tags: nancy

I'm trying to utilize embedded views feature of NancyFX, but could not manage to make it happen. I've used that [example](http://simoncropp.com/embeddingviewsasresourcesinnancyfx). But still, it looks like Nancy does not use `ResourceViewLocationProvider` to locate my view.

My bootstrapp configuration,

```
    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(IKernel existingContainer)
    {
        base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(existingContainer);

        var currentAssembly = GetType().Assembly;
        ResourceViewLocationProvider.RootNamespaces.Add(currentAssembly, "Candidate.Nancy.SelfHosted.Views");
    }

    protected override NancyInternalConfiguration InternalConfiguration
    {
        get { return NancyInternalConfiguration.WithOverrides(x => x.ViewLocationProvider = typeof(ResourceViewLocationProvider)); }
    }
```

My module,

```
public class AccountModule : NancyModule
{
    private readonly IUserManagement _userManagement;

    public AccountModule(IUserManagement userManagement) : base("/account")
    {
        _userManagement = userManagement;
        Get["/login"] = p => View["Login.cshtml"];
    }
}
```

Login.cshtml is placed under /Views/Account/Login.cshtml and marked as embedded resource.

If I run application, I got HTTP 500. Seems to me, it tries to find it on filesystem instead of assembly resources.

> Nancy.RequestExecutionException: Oh noes! --->
>   Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewNotFoundException: Unable to locate view
>   'Login.cshtml' Currently available view engine extensions:
>   sshtml,html,htm,cshtml,vbhtml Locations inspected:
>   Login.cshtml,views/Login.cshtml,views/account/Login.cshtml,account/Login.cshtml,views/Account/Login.cshtml,Account/Login.cshtml
>   Root path:
>   D:\Development\Projects\candidate.net\src\Candidate.Nancy.Selfhosted\bin\Debug
>   at Nancy.ViewEngines.DefaultViewFactory.GetRenderedView(String
>   viewName, Object model, ViewLocationContext viewLocationContext)    at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)    at
>   Nancy.ViewEngines.DefaultViewFactory.RenderView(String viewName,
>   Object model, ViewLocationContext viewLocationContext)    at
>   Nancy.NancyModule.ViewRenderer.get_Item(String viewName)    at
>   Candidate.Nancy.Selfhosted.Modules.AccountModule.<.ctor>b__0(Object p)
>   in
>   D:\Development\Projects\candidate.net\src\Candidate.Nancy.Selfhosted\Modules\AccountModule.cs:line
>   17    at Nancy.Routing.Route.Invoke(DynamicDictionary parameters)
>   at Nancy.NancyEngine.ResolveAndInvokeRoute(NancyContext context)    at
>   Nancy.NancyEngine.InvokeRequestLifeCycle(NancyContext context,
>   IPipelines pipelines)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at Nancy.NancyEngine.InvokeOnErrorHook(NancyContext context,
>   ErrorPipeline pipeline, Exception ex)

**UPDATE:** This issue has been [resolved](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/705#issuecomment-8808424) in Nancy 0.12.1.0.

Comment: This may have been a bug, can you try it with the latest nancy from master on github and see if that fixes it?

Comment: Does your bootstrapper inherit from DefaultNancyBootstrapper?

Comment: @PatrickSteele I'm using NinjectNancyBootstrapper